# errors trying to read file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, text-files, streamreader

I am trying to make a page that lets me read a log file from a chat room that I am monitoring...I am having the hardest time trying to get this to work for some reason...i have taken bits and pieces of code to get what i have working...but it still either doesn't display at all OR after about 200 lines, it stops reading each line but instead make it one big mess of text...here is what i have for code

```
Protected Sub bView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bView.Click
    Response.Write(Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text))
    lFileOut.Text = ""
    Try
        Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text)
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim cont As String
        Do
            cont = objStreamReader.ReadLine()
            lFileOut.Text = lFileOut.Text & cont & "<br>"
        Loop Until cont Is Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is a test file i have been testing everything on...it just doesn't do anything nor does it throw any error...i am completely stumped on this one.

[Test File](http://pervsgame.com/other%20stuff/testdoc.rar)

Please let me know you you know anything that would help

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? That's **kind of** important information to include.

Comment: Your variable `cont` is probably `Nothing` after your last line.. rework your loop so it uses the line only if not nothing.

Comment: it isn't throwing any errors - it either displays part of the file or nothing at all - and 95% of the time it is nothing at all

Comment: I figured it out...the username are in <brackets> and it thinks it is a html tag...time to &gt; &lt;

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub bView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bView.Click
    Response.Write(Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text))
    lFileOut.Text = ""
    Try
        Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text)
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim cont As String
        cont = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        cont = cont.Replace(">", "&gt;")
        cont = cont.Replace("<", "&lt;")
        cont = cont.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>")
        cont = cont.Replace(vbLf, "<br>")
        cont = cont.Replace(vbCr, "<br>")

        lFileOut.Text = lFileOut.Text & cont & "<br>"

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I figured it out...the username are in  and it thinks it is a html tag...time to:

```
&gt; &lt;
```